# Problems with APC with Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, apc, magento-1.9

I just had my server people install APC to try to decrease the amount of memory that my server uses per person.

I went into my local.xml and entered in the following within the Global mark.
   `<cache>`
    `<backend>apc</backend>`
    `<slow_backend>database</slow_backend>`
    `<prefix>MYSTORE_</prefix>`
   `</cache>`
    `</global>`
I then reset apache.

Then in my php.ini file I have the following:
    `;APC SETTINGS`
    `apc.enabled=1`
    `apc.shm_size=512M`
   `apc.num_files_hint=10000`
    `apc.user_entries_hint=10000`
    `apc.max_file_size=10M`
    `apc.stat=0`
    `apc.optimization=0`
    `apc.shm_segments=1`
    `apc.enable_cli=1`
    `apc.cache_by_default=1`
    `apc.include_once_override=1`

I was able to increase the size and actually enter in these settings buy updating the master php.ini on my server (rather than the local one).

However, when I go into system cached entires it only shows *hidden*/apc.php and on the dashboard it only shows the 1 file.

Can you guys please help me figure this out? I'm running magento 1.9.1, PHP 5.4.35, APC 3.1.13, Apache 2.2.29.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing

extension=apc.so

Also APC is at the server/php level.  The cache block in the XML is to configure higher level caching systems such as Redis.